# jQuery can't access the sought DOM element

Tags: jquery, html, dom, css-selectors

I have the following HTML elements;

```
<div id="divOrderContainer">
 <ul id="ulOrders">
<li id="liAck">
  <div id="divViewOrderTitle"></div>
  <div id="divViewOrderSpacer"></div>
  <div id="divAcknowledgeItems"></div>              
</li>
<li id="liTemp">
  <div id="divViewOrderTitle">test</div>
  <div id="divViewOrderSpacer"></div>
  <div id="divTempItems"></div>
</li>
 </ul>          
</div>
```

On page ready, I do an ajax request, then upon response I will insert it into the existing DOM tree like;

```
htmlBuilder_Temp = htmlBuilder_Temp + '<li><table id="tableTemp">' +
 '<tr>' +
'<th>Ia</th>' +
'<th>Den</th>' +
'<th>Unt</th>' +
'<th>Ory</th>' +
'<th></th>' +
 '</tr>';               
htmlBuilder_Temp = htmlBuilder_Temp + 
 '<tr>' +
'<td> a </td>' +
'<td ""> +b+ </td>' +
'<td> +c+ </td>' +
'<td> +d+ </td>' +
'<td><span id="span'+posid+'">delete<span></td>' +
 '</tr>';           
htmlBuilder_Ack = htmlBuilder_Ack + '</table></li>';
```

The appending of the new elements is "ALWAYS" a success,

So here's my problem, I wanted to attach a click handler to every span under

```
Table>tr>td>span,
```

that when clicked would alert me the element id however, when I try to check if the click handler is attached there wasn't any,

Click Handler Code:

```
$("#divTempItem > table > tbody > tr").('click', 'td span', function(){
   alert($(this).attr("id");
});
```

I also tried;

```
$("#tableTemp").on('click', 'tr td span', function(){
   alert($(this).attr("id");
});
```

But to no avail, it seems I am not able to reach the specific DOM element that I am looking for... Accessing the name "span"+number doesn't resolve my issue,

Am I missing something,

Here's a view of the output DOM tree; I have removed the ending tags on the end, I think this would be enough...

```
<div id="divOrderContainer">
   <ul id="ulOrders">
      <li id="liAck"></li>
      <li id="liTemp">
          <div id="divViewOrderTitle">test</div>
          <div id="divViewOrderSpacer"></div>
          <div id="divTempItems">
            <li>
               <table id="tableTemp">
                  <tbody>
                     <tr>                         
                       <td> a </td>
                       <td> b </td>
                       <td> c </td>
                       <td> d </td>
                       <td><span id="span8">delete</span></td>
                     </tr>                         
                   </tbody>
                </table>
```

Who automagically created the "TBODY" element anyway?

Thanks..

Comment: Your HTML has multiple objects with the same ID. This is not valid. You can only use an ID once in the HTML document.

Comment: Why do you have the `""` in this: `'<td ""> +b+ </td>'`?

Comment: I have updated the DOM, my apologies for the misrepresentation..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description of the problem it seems, from the Ajax part, that the table isn't present in the DOM at the point at which events are being bound, instead I'd suggest binding to the `li` element which is present in the DOM from `DOMReady`:

```
$('#divTempItems li').on('click', 'td', function(e){
    alert(this.id);
});
```

Note that your HTML is invalid (as pasted in the latter code block), as an `li` must appear in, and only in, a `ul` or `ol` element, and `div` elements cannot be direct children of either a `ul` or `ol`. Also duplicate `id`s are invalid, an `id` ***must*** be unique within the document.

The `tbody` is automatically created by most, if not all, browsers when rendering table elements. While the spec, as I recall, says that they're optional, browsers, it seems, disagree.

Comment: You were absolutely right about this, I have been mixing elements all together and since HTML isn't strict enough to spit out the error, you are nowhere but on a limbo of debugging code over and over again and looking thru it by yourself is just another daunting if not frustrating task as a programmer... hmmm... anyway, thanks for pointing it out for me... A simple mistake that causes a lot of troubles

Comment: Just to clear my confusion, you've said that "div" elements cannot be direct children of either a "ul or ol" does that mean that I can't create something like "<ul><li><div></div></li></ul>" since "div" here would become a direct child of <li>?

Comment: No, in that example the `div` would be a 'direct child' of the `li`, which is fine,  it's just that a `div` can't have a `ul` or `ol` as it's parent (ancestor is fine, but parent is a no-go).

Answer (score 0):

may be you can change this line:

```
'<td><span id="span'+posid+'">delete<span></td>' +
```

to

```
'<td><span id="span'+posid+'" onclick='+'"delete(this)">delete<span></td>' +
```

and the function is

```
function delete(obj){
   alert($(obj).arrt('id'));
}
```